# how i will generate C/C++ code from simulink model or m file that can individually run on c compiler

Tags: matlab, simulink

how i will generate C/C++ code from simulink model or m file that can individually run on c compiler like visual studio/turbo c without help of matlab compiler like MCR ,MCS and so on?

Answer (score 3):

Use the add-on products MATLAB Coder and Simulink Coder.